# Redis - can't [BG]SAVE after one failure

Tags: redis, save, persistence

I have a message in the Redis log saying

> BeginForkOperation: system error caught. error code=0x00000000, message=Forked process did not respond in a timely mannager.: unknown error
>   Can't save in background: fork: Invalid argument

This message appeared in the log more than a week ago, and since then, each time I'm trying to run "BGSAVE" or "SAVE", it throws the "err background save already in progress" error..

I can't see another redis-server process except the main process in the task manager, nor in "client list" command.

I'm using the [Redis on windows project](http://msopentech.com/opentech-projects/redis/) (constraints:)

Any ideas how to tell the Redis there's no background save process and force it to save the data into the disk, before it crashes?

Comment: What version of Redis are you using?  If you are using an older version, try upgrading.  Issue Reference: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/144

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue and i solve it like this.You need to update your redis version(mine is 5.0.14.1 updated version right now). https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases you can use this and has a doc video on youtube.